# Select from where contains

Tags: ms-access, contains

I have a database where i can add a full name of a person, and i am trying to implement a search function using a textBox and a button but i only want to search for the first or last name not necessarily entering the full name.

I tried using SELECT FROM WHERE CONTAINS like this:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE CONTAINS (column, '"+textBox.Text+"')";
```

But i keep getting this error:

```
Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'CONTAINS (column,'the text i tried to search')'.
```

I also tried changing the + to % or * or & but still it didn’t work.

Comment: which database are you using ?

Comment: I am using an access database

Answer (score 1):

*Contains* is not valid Access SQL. Use *Like*:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [YourNameField] Like '*" + textBox.Text + "*')";
```

Comment: Note that the **'\*'** are required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a search such as you want:

```
Private Sub cmdFind_DisplayName_Click()
    Dim dbs As Database, rstPatient As Recordset
    Dim txtDisplayName, strQuote As String
    strQuote = Chr$(34)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Me.OrderBy = "DISPLAYNAME"
    Me.OrderByOn = True

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rstPatient = Me.RecordsetClone
    txtDisplayName = Trim(InputBox("Please Enter Patient Name ", "Patient Find By Name"))
    txtDisplayName = UCase(txtDisplayName) & "*"
    If IsNull(txtDisplayName) Then
        MsgBox ("No Patient Name Entered - Please Enter a Valid Patient Name")
    Else
        rstPatient.FindFirst "[DISPLAYNAME] Like " & strQuote & txtDisplayName & strQuote
        If Not (rstPatient.NoMatch) Then
            Me.Bookmark = rstPatient.Bookmark
            Me.Refresh
        Else
            MsgBox ("Patient Not Found - Please Enter a New Patient Name")
        End If
    End If

    GoTo Exit_cmdFind_Click

    ErrorHandler:
        MsgBox LTrim(RTrim(Me.NAME)) + "." + "Patient Find By Display Name - " + "Error: " + AccessError(Err.Number)

    Exit_cmdFind_Click:
      rstPatient.Close
      Set dbs = Nothing
      Set rstPatient = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Create 1 textbox (txtMain) and search command button(btnSearch) to execute SQL. Then add a listbox (listResult) to display results.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()

Dim mainSQL As String

mainSQL = " SELECT YOUR_FIELD_NAME " & _
      " FROM MasterReg " & _
      " WHERE Left(,InStr(YOUR_FULL_NAME_FIELD,' ')-1) LIKE '" &  me.txtMain & "*'"  & _ ' Firstname Search
      " OR RIGHT( YOUR_FULL_NAME_FIELD,Len( YOUR_FULL_NAME_FIELD )-InStr( YOUR_FULL_NAME_FIELD,' ')) LIKE '" &  me.txtMain & "*'" 'Surname Search                   

Me.listResult.SetFocus               
Me.listResult.RowSource = mainSQL
Me.listResult.Requery

End Sub
```